# Floating/Clearing Divs, Responsive Design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a problem with 5 floating divs, here is a picture:

[image: 5 floating divs]

You will see.. the green div should be on the left side from the red div(instead of the empty place) and the violet div on the place from the green div.
The html order from the divs is: blue, red, orange, green and violet, I think this is the reason for this white, empty space, because the green and the violet div comes in the html after! the red div, is this right?
What can i do, to fix this problem, anyone have an idea? I set the margin-top of the violet to -300px but I think this not a clean solution and than would be the order(html structure) false.

**Here is my full html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ResponsiveExample</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
        <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <header>
                <div class="header">
                </div>
                <div class="below-header"></div>
            </header>

            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="blue-box"></div>
                <div class="red-box"></div>
                <div class="orange-box"></div>
                <div class="green-box"></div>
                <div class="violet-box"></div>
            </div>

            <footer>

            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And here is my CSS:**

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}    
.header{
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
} 
.below-header{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}    
.blue-box{
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
}   
.red-box{
    height: 600px;
    background-color: red;
}

.orange-box{
    height: 300px;
    background-color: orange;
}
.green-box{
    height: 300px;
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
.violet-box{
    height: 300px;
    background-color: violet;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 28.125em) {
    .blue-box{
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .red-box
    {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .orange-box{
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .green-box{
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 71.875em){
        .blue-box{
            width: 33%;
            border: 5px solid black;
        }
        .red-box{
            width: 33%;
            border: 5px solid black;   
        }
        .orange-box{
            width: 33%;
            border: 5px solid black;
            clear: right;        
        }
        .green-box{
           width: 33%;
           border: 5px solid black;
           clear: right;

        }
        .violet-box{
            width: 33%;
            //margin-top: -300px;
            border: 5px solid black;
           float: left;
        }   
    }   
}
```

I would be very grateful for every help that I get!

Comment: AFAIK you can't do it CSS only. There are some javascript libraries like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which do it.

Comment: One way to do it would be enclosing `blue` and `green`into one "side" div and enclosing `purple` and `orange` into another "side" div. Otherwise you can't do it without javascript.

Comment: Sifu has the right idea. If you enclosed your Blue and Green into a transparent div, the same size and shape as your Red, that would probably do what you want. You're just going to need more wrapping elements/divs.

Comment: No this should be responsive.. when I wrap the blue and the green div in one div, I would have troubles in the other views.
How can I fix this problem with javascript?

Comment: At Desktop Screen try to set position of all elements absolute..it will help you

Comment: http://salvattore.com/ - masonry layout

Comment: thank you that look very interesting and useful!
grateful, Nico

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div id="left">
         <div class="blue-box"></div>
         <div class="green-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="center">
         <div class="red-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div class="orange-box"></div>
        <div class="purple-box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then apply CSS styles to your liking.

Comment: Oke this would be work in this view, but my example should be responsive, pls watch my code and resize the window, than you would know what problem I have.

Comment: Yes. The code I've given can be made responsive with the right CSS styles, applied at the right viewpoints. On a mobile screen, the boxes can be stacked on top of each other, or side by side -- whatever method you prefer. Ideally, for best results, you should have an even number of elements in a div (2, 4, 6, 8, etc). You have 5 (an odd number). Making them responsive is going to be a bit more trickier.

Comment: than I can always wrap 2 divs in 1? do you mean that?